# Extract string from HTML

Tags: c#, string

I want to extract the string **KLE3KAN918D429** from the following html code:

```
<td class="Labels"> CODE (Sp Number): </td><td width="40.0%"> KLE3KAN918D429</td>
```

Is there a method in C# where I can specify the source-text , start string , end string and get the string between start and end ?

Comment: FYI : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 Better use an HTML Parser like HTML Agility Pack

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are, as per the comments, probably better off using a parsing library to iterate the DOM structure but if you can make some assumptions about the html you'll be parsing, you could do something like below:

```
var html = "<td class=\"Labels\"> CODE (Sp Number): </td><td width=\"40.0%\"> KLE3KAN918D429</td>";
var labelIndex = html.IndexOf("<td class=\"Labels\">");
var pctIndex = html.IndexOf("%", labelIndex);
var closeIndex = html.IndexOf("<", pctIndex);
var key = html.Substring(pctIndex + 3, closeIndex - pctIndex - 3).Trim();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(key);
```

Likely quite brittle but sometimes quick and dirty is all that is required.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. I thought there will be one-line solution  to this problem :)

Comment: There is if you wrap this as a function which is all any one liner really is ;)

Answer (score 1):

As others already suggested, you should use something like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) for parsing html. Don't use regular expressions or other hacks for parsing html.

You have several `td` nodes in your html string. Getting last one is really easy with `td[last()]` XPath:

```
string html = "<td class=\"Labels\"> CODE (Sp Number): </td><td width=\"40.0%\"> KLE3KAN918D429</td>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var td = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("td[last()]");
var result = td.InnerText.Trim(); // "KLE3KAN918D429"
```

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest using HTMLAgilityPack for this.

It's as easy as:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"<td class=""Labels""> CODE (Sp Number): </td><td width=""40.0%""> KLE3KAN918D429</td>");

var tdNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='Labels' and text()=' CODE (Sp Number): ']/following-sibling::td[1]");
Console.WriteLine(tdNode.InnerText.Trim());
```

Before you start, add HtmlAgilityPack from NuGet:

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```